# which happened = happening?

Tags: reduced-relative-clauses, participle-phrases

I'd like to know whether the "which + verb" sequence can be rewritten as V-ing in the following sentences:

> a. The joy and excitement of the successful landing for the Perseverance rover and Ingenuity helicopter, **which took** place during a time of hardship for so many, echoed around the globe.

> b. The joy and excitement of the successful landing for the Perseverance rover and Ingenuity helicopter, **taking** place during a time of hardship for so many, echoed around the globe.

> c. The shooting incident **which happened** in the city has shocked people all over the world.

> d. The shooting incident **happening** in the city has shocked people all over the world.

Comment: As usual, Apollyon, you must tell us what you already understand and show what research you've done